# Three.js / Blender / morph animation - no colour / color

Tags: three.js, blender

Does anyone have a working example of a morph animation exported from blender then loaded into three.js.

The examples on git all have an extra array in the .js (flamingo.js etc.) for the models called 'morphColors', blender doesn't seem to export any colour information (I am using the dev version of the exporter), so I end up with an object that animates fine but is black and white.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`morphColors` didn't seem to be exported in the previous exporter as well.

```
14:36 ~/work/www/threejs/three.js-r69/utils/exporters/blender/2.65/scripts/addons/io_mesh_threejs
$ grep "morphColors" *.py
14:36 ~/work/www/threejs/three.js-r69/utils/exporters/blender/2.65/scripts/addons/io_mesh_threejs
```

Even with the older exporter there was a `generatedBy` attribute that was included in the metadata to indicate the exporter used. I do not see this in the `flamingo.js` file. Tho I can't say for sure I suspect that this file may have been the result of possible manual editing, unless there is an exporter from a different 3D package that does what you are looking for.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/models/animated/flamingo.js

Comment: tldr; the lack of metadata makes it hard to say where/how the `flamingo.js` file was generated.

Comment: Here is a link to my blender file; http://www.playnicely.com/demos/Sun-1-tree.blend I just can't seem to find the right settings to go get the animation and the materials to export correctly, the model always comes out black and white.

Comment: Haven't looked at this but there is more going on than just the data in the asset file. Even in the example scene the developer had to create helper functions it seemed. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_morphnormals.html#L152

I looked at the loader source code and it does't seem to do much with this color information other than just store it in an array.